# Fluent Nhibernate - selecting specific column and count query with group by

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I'm having some trouble excuting a query in fluent nhibernate.
I have a table : Books with the following columns:

```
ID, NAME, YEAR, BOOK_TYPE, AUTHOR_ID
```

I want to excute the following sql query in Fluent NHibernate:

```
SELECT BOOK_TYPE, COUNT(*)
FROM BOOKS
GROUP BY BOOK_TYPE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So called *Fluent-NHibernate* is just a mapping extension. To get data we need NHibernate built n querying features: `ICriteria`, `QueryOver` or even a *LINQ*.

Based on the documentation we can use projections for the above case, using the `QueryOver` API

#### [16.6. QueryOver - Projections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)

The code snippet:

```
IList selection =
    session.QueryOver<Book>()
        .SelectList(list => list
            .Select(c => c.BooktType)
            .SelectCount(c => c.ID))
        .List<object[]>();
```